# MySQL python Foreign Keys not functioning properly

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am trying to add a foreign key to one table that references another table however whenever I run the program the field in the table with the foreign key it displays NONE. The code is as follows

```
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Basic(pnid INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,Arena VARCHAR(25), CreateDate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)")
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Units(pnid INT, bid INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, SerialNumber VARCHAR(25), BuildNumber VARCHAR(25), CurrentDate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)")

         cur.execute("INSERT INTO Basic(Arena) VALUES(%s)", arenanumber)
         cur.execute("ALTER TABLE Units ADD FOREIGN KEY(pnid) REFERENCES Basic(pnid);")
         cur.execute("INSERT INTO Units(SerialNumber) VALUES(%s)", serialnumber)
         cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Units")
         print cur.fetchall()
```

This returns a None in the pnid colunm

Answer (score 1):

When inserting a row into the Units table, you need to specify what pnid.  In your example you have a new table, only 1 row, but if you have 100 entries in the Basic table, the database doesn't know which entry in the Basic table to associate the Unit with.  In your example where it looks like you want to put the Unit on the entry you just made in the Basic you should be able to use LAST_INSERT_ID() to identify the id, so I think it becomes something like the following:

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Basic(pnid INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,Arena VARCHAR(25), CreateDate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)")
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Units(pnid INT, bid INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, SerialNumber VARCHAR(25), BuildNumber VARCHAR(25), CurrentDate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Basic(Arena) VALUES(%s)", arenanumber)
cur.execute("ALTER TABLE Units ADD FOREIGN KEY(pnid) REFERENCES Basic(pnid);")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Units(SerialNumber,pnid) VALUES(%s,LAST_INSERT_ID())", serialnumber)
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Units")
print cur.fetchall()
```

If this doesn't work (I don't have the ability to test it at the moment), you may need to do a SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() and store it to a variable and then use that in your insert into Units.

Comment: The MySQLdb Python package provides the last created ID on `cursor.lastrowid`